# Maria DB - Before Insert Trigger assign value to NEW.field

Tags: triggers, mariadb

i am new for this, background is totally based on Oracle and related products. i have installed XAMPP 3.3.0,  i have created a trigger which works fine.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE OR REPLACE 
    TRIGGER bi_cancel_booking BEFORE INSERT
    ON cancelled_booking
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    --
    DECLARE next_receipt VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE rct_no INT(5);
    --
    SELECT MAX(starting_number)+1, CONCAT(receipt_prefix,'-',MAX(starting_number)+1)
      INTO rct_no, next_receipt 
      FROM com_receipt_types
     WHERE receipt_type = 'Cancel Booking';

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

but when using NEW.cancel_receipt_no (see below code) it is showing error : Error Code: 1327 Undeclared variable: NEW

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE OR REPLACE 
    TRIGGER bi_cancel_booking BEFORE INSERT
    ON cancelled_booking
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    --
    DECLARE next_receipt VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE rct_no INT(5);
    --
    SELECT MAX(starting_number)+1, CONCAT(receipt_prefix,'-',MAX(starting_number)+1)
      INTO rct_no, NEW.cancel_receipt_no
      FROM com_receipt_types
     WHERE receipt_type = 'Cancel Booking';

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

is there any restriction that i cannot assign the value to NEW.field as in my first code here **when i am trying to assign the value as: NEW.cancel_receipt_no := next_receipt then it also showing error**. please help, how i can do this here?

Answer (score 0):

i used below code and error has gone (used SET):

**SET NEW.cancel_receipt_no = next_receipt;**

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE OR REPLACE 
TRIGGER bi_cancel_booking BEFORE INSERT
ON cancelled_booking
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
--
DECLARE next_receipt VARCHAR(20);
DECLARE rct_no INT(5);
--
SELECT MAX(starting_number)+1, CONCAT(receipt_prefix,'-',MAX(starting_number)+1)
  INTO rct_no, next_receipt 
  FROM com_receipt_types
 WHERE receipt_type = 'Cancel Booking';

    SET NEW.cancel_receipt_no := next_receipt;
    
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

it was because of my lack of knowledge, gradually i will learn the things with help of all seniors here.